# Javax annotation constrainst @ReportAsSingleViolation

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I use the Spring Framework and bean validation spec (hibernate implementation). Considering the code snippet below, I made the following observation using `@ReportAsSingleViolation`:

- Only the default message is returned when `@ReportAsSingleViolation` is added. My expectation is to have the message that trigger the failure and not the default.
- When I remove the `@ReportAsSingleViolation` annotation, everything works as expected. All error messages corresponding to the violated constraints are correctly returned.

Is this behavior describes part of a Bean validation spec or is it an implementation issue?

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
//@ReportAsSingleViolation
@NotBlank(message = "The input cannot be blank")
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9A-Z_]+", message = "The input must content only uppercase, numbers and undescore")
@Size(max = 30, message = "The input must be maximal 30")
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation{

    String message() default "{com.example.MyAnnotation.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly the purpose of `@ReportAsSingleViolation`: composing constraints and reporting them as a single one with a unified message.

It's indeed the behavior defined by the spec.

Quoting the spec:

> It is possible to ensure that composing annotations do not raise individual error reports. In this scenario, if one or more composing annotations are invalid, the main constraint is automatically considered invalid and the corresponding error report is generated. To mark a constraint as raising a single constraint error report if either the composed or one of the composing constraints fail, use the @ReportAsSingleViolation annotation.

If you want only one violation with its specific error message, you can use the Hibernate Validator-specific fail fast mode but be aware that it won't return one violation per property, just the first one failing for your bean.

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-fail-fast for more details about the fail fast mode.